# Python, remove all numbers from sublist

Tags: python, string, types, casting, int

I have the following list: [['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S', 3, 7], ['C', 3, 'D']]

But I want to have: [['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S'], ['C', 'D']]

the elements in the list are all str objects. so basically this question is asking how can i get python to recognize a number even if it is cast as a string?

Comment: If they're all string objects then show them as such, put quotes around the ints.

Comment: The answers you've been given, both here and in your previous question, can easily be adapted to check if the string can be parsed as an int. Instead of `isinstance` use a different function. Look up "python how to test if string is number" or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> l = [['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S', 3, 7], ['C', 3, 'D']]
>>> [[item for item in sublist if not isinstance(item, int)] for sublist in l]
[['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S'], ['C', 'D']]
```

If you need to handle digits inside strings also, [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) would help:

```
>>> l = [['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S', '3', '7'], ['C', '3', 'D']]
>>> [[item for item in sublist if not item.isdigit()] for sublist in l]
[['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S'], ['C', 'D']]
```

Comment: when i run this i get the same list as i started with, the numbers are not removed

Comment: but if i change isinstance(item, int) to isinstance(item, str) then everything gets removed.

Comment: @abcla have you checked the second part of the answer? Thanks.